# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I am new to programming C.. please tell me what is wrong with this program, and why I am getting this error: **error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'**....

```
extern void func();

int main(int argc, char ** argv){
    func();
    int i=1;
    for(;i<=5; i++) {
        register int number = 7;
        printf("number is %d\n", number++);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: I haven't used visual in at least 8 years, but does Visual's limited C compiler support allow mixed code and variables?  Is the line of the error on the declaration for int i=1; ??  Try moving it above the call to func();    Also, I would use extern void func(void);

Comment: You're not showing the full code. The snipped in question is fine and should not produce any syntax errors.

Comment: @RandyHoward: I believe that's the problem: Visual C doesn't permit mixing declarations and statements, a feature added to C by the 1999 ISO standard, which Visual Studio doesn't support. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: You're missing the required `#include <stdio.h>`, plus the `#include` for whatever header defines `getch` (`<conio.h>`, I think).

Comment: Fair enough, @KeithThompson, I thought so but it's been a while.  I don't think his example was meant to compile completely.  Since he doesn't return a value from main() either.

Comment: @RandyHoward: Not returning a value from `main()` isn't illegal. In C89/C90, it returns a undefined status to the environment. In C99, it's equivalent to `return 0;`.

Comment: I was being somewhat facetious, but yes.

Comment: It would be clearer to do the initial assignment to `i` in the `for` loop: `int i; for (i = 1; i <= 5; i ++) ...`. (You could declare it there as well if MS supported C99.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I haven't used visual in at least 8 years, but it seems that Visual's limited C compiler support does not allow mixed code and variables. Is the line of the error on the declaration for `int i=1;` ?? Try moving it above the call to `func();`

Also, I would use `extern void func(void);`

Answer (score 35):

Visual Studio only supports C89.  That means that all of your variables must be declared before anything else at the top of a function.

EDIT: @KeithThompson prodded me to add a more technically accurate description (and really just correct where mine is not in one regard).  All declarations (of variables or of anything else) must precede all statements within a block.

Comment: Actually it means that all declarations (of variables or of anything else) must precede all statements *within a block*.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Definitely a more technically correct response.

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
int i=1;
for(;i<=5; i++) {
```

should be idiomatically written as:

```
for(int i=1; i<=5; i++) {
```

because there no point to declare `for` loop variable in the function scope.

Comment: @EdS. this way the variable is declared in the `for` block and this should fix his problem.

Comment: That syntax is only valid in C++ and C99, not in C89.  Visual Studio only supports the C89 dialect of C.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield i've used this syntax in VS2003, should not have changed much since then.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: And even if it were VS did support C99, that wouldn't answer the OP's question. That part of the code could be improved, but it's perfectly legal in all versions of C.

Comment: @lenik: Visual Studio supports both C and C++ (and seems to prefer C++). The C++ support is pretty good, which means you can declare variables in `for` loop headers and mix declarations and statements *in C++*. If you compile your code as C (by naming your file with a `.c` extension), it only supports the 1989/1990 C standard (with a very few extensions such as `//` comments, I think) -- which means you can't use even feature that exist in both C99 and C++.

Comment: I'm not convinced that Visual's C support is sandboxed to C89 either.  They have some extensions which appear in C99, and lots of other differences.  Just like how gcc -std=c89 -pedantic will *still* allow many C99 features to compile without warning.  It doesn't sandbox the feature set completely, although the option names might convince you otherwise.

Comment: @KeithThompson: The syntax `for(int i=1; ...)` which declares a variable inside the `for` statement is not valid in C89.  Try compiling it with `gcc -std=c89` or `clang -std=c89`.  Whether VS supports that syntax as an extension to C code, I can't say for sure.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield: VS 2010 Express does *not* support either declaration in for loop headers or mixed declarations and statements for C programs. It does support `//` comments. (Of course it supports all of these for C++.)