# Strange syntax error C2143 in Visual only (missing ';' before 'type')

Tags: c, visual-studio, macros, syntax-error, c-preprocessor

I'm getting a strange compilation error for a **C** code in MSVC only. More precisely:

> error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

C2143 is a fairly generic error, and there are myriad of questions on SO around it, but none of them seems to apply so far.
The closest one can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697190/error-c2143-syntax-error-missing-before-type), and stress the importance of declaring variables at the beginning of a block, which seems to have been respected here.

Here is a sample code:

```
#define       NB_LL 6
typedef struct { long long ll[NB_LL ]; } stateSpace_t;
#define ALLOCATE_ONSTACK(stateName)  stateSpace_t stateName##_s; void* stateName = (void*) &(stateName##_s);
```

The following code works well:

```
void f1()
{
    ALLOCATE_ONSTACK(state1);
    /* do something */
}
```

This one doesn't:

```
void f2()
{
    ALLOCATE_ONSTACK(state1);
    ALLOCATE_ONSTACK(state2);   // <--- error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
    /* do something */
}
```

The second code works well with GCC, so the issue seems restricted to MSVC.
My understanding is that macro `ALLOCATE_ONSTACK()` only do variable declaration and initialization, so it seems to respect **C** syntax.

Is it?

Comment: Also works fine for me using `llvm-gcc`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, this one is fairly convoluted.

Look at the

```
#define ALLOCATE_ONSTACK(stateName)
```

It ends with a `;` character.

Now look at your code :

```
ALLOCATE_ONSTACK(state1);
```

It also ends with a `';'` character. That means that, on this particular line, you have 2 following `';'` characters.

Since MSVC is not C99, it requires all declarations to be done at the beginning of the block. Since you have two `';'` characters following each other, it acts as if the declaration area was ended. So, when you declare other variables in :

```
ALLOCATE_ONSTACK(state2);
```

it then fails, syntax error.

GCC has no such problem since it is C99.

Either remove the `';'` character at the end of the macro, or within your source code. Only one is required. Not sure which solution is better...

[Edit] : As suggested in comments and other answer, removing the semicolon from the macro looks the better solution.

Comment: That's definitely convoluted... :) Thanks for the clear explanation. Now to select where to remove the semicolon...

Comment: which is better, I voted to first one, just remove the ';' at the end of the macro, cus' this make source code looks more reasonable is it? :)

Comment: @billhoo : yeah, I second that :)

Answer (score 4):

You have a semi-colon at the end of the ALLOCATE_ONSTACK macro definition and also at the end of the invocation. This means that you effectively have a null statement after each macro expansion. Because of this, the second expansion is not at the beginning of the block.

Classically, C has required that all declarations occur in a block before the first non-declaration statement. gcc relaxes this requirement so the error doesn't occur.

I'd suggest rewriting your macro definition without the trailing semicolon.

Edit: beat to the punch.

Comment: Thanks, indeed same answer. I'll remove the semicolon from the macro.